# Unexpectedly found nil after checking for nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, null

I am trying to save a Firebase username to UserDefault. Here is what I have:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("Users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("log in 4")
    print(snapshot.value)
    if snapshot.value != nil {
        print("log in 4.1")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(snapshot.value!["username"], forKey: "username")//Crash probably occurs here
        print("log in 4.2")
    }

})
```

The system prints `log in 4` and `log in 4.1`, but not 4.2. The error must be occurring on the line in between. I check that `snapshot.value` isn't nil, but it still prints nil. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: `snapshot.value["username"]` will return nil if there is no value for the `username` key in the dictionary. You should learn to use the debugger and single stepping rather than relying on log statements.

Comment: @Paulw11 why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: It may not be the answer (OK, it probably is) but I prefer to give the asker an opportunity to confirm in comments before posting an answer

Comment: Fair enough :) it is worth mentioning that everything can be nicely checked with `if let username = snapshot.value?["username"]` ;)

Comment: @Paulw11 yes hat was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently are just checking that `snapshot.value` contains *any* value, so is not `nil`. But that doesn't mean that `snapshot.value` contains the value `"username"`.

If it is empty initialized, it isn't nil either.

So to check for this specific key you'd have to add a check for the key itself:

```
if let userValue = snapshot.value?["username"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use optional binding to get the value you want to unwrap...

```
if let username = snapshot.value?["username"] {
    // now you can use username safely
}
```